# Sort users by karma in thumbs_up Rails Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Is it possible to sort users by how much karma they have from getting votes on their voteable objects in the thumbs_up Rails gem? If anyone could detail the scope code required I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do this would be to have a column in the `users` table that stores the total amount of karma points a user has.

Set the default to `0`. And then in your `karma_controller`, you can put a `after_save` call back that updates the associated user's `karma_count` field every time that user is rated.

Then all you need to do is `User.order("karma_count asc")`

That should be enough to point you in the right direction.